# Array to cv2 frame in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing, numpy-ndarray, python-gstreamer

I have gstreamer buffer and like to convert to cv2 frame in python multiprocessing

`Gstreamer` gets buffer from camera in one process and buffer is passed to another process using `Multprocessing.Array`

```
Gstreamer gets buffer in one process as
    processing=Multiprocess.process(target=imageprocess, args=(sharedarray,))
    sharedarray=Array['d',6220800,dtype=np.uint8]
    sample = sink.emit("pull_sample")
    buf=sample.get_buffer()
    sharedarray=np.frombuffer(buffer=buf.extract_dup(0,buf.get_size()),dtype=np.uint8)
```

I checked and sharedarray has length 6220800.

Then in another process,

```
def imageprocess(img):
    image=np.frombuffer(img,dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.imshow('image ', image.reshape(1080,1920,3))
```

If I set dtype=np.uint8, I have error as
cannot reshape array of size 49766400 into shape (1080,1920,3).

Only no error, if I set dtype=np.float64, but I have black image.

How to have correct image in this issue?
I can convert image type from double to char in cv2, but wonder why source has uint8 and np.frombuffer can't retrieve uint8 directly.

Comment: it looks that the img is somewhere implicitly converted to float64. More code may be necessary to find the source of the bug.

Comment: This may be unrelated issue to your problem but you assign variable "sharedarray" twice. In means that the first object Array[] is destroyed without being used.

Comment: @tstanisl yes in `sharedarray=Array['d',6220800,dtype=np.uint8]` d is double and I need to change to correct format. Thank you

Comment: Now changed to ShardArray `https://pypi.org/project/SharedArray/` and things are solved